# How to find 2 pictures via iMacros

Tags: imacros

For example:

On the page are 3 diferent picture

```
http://example.com/1.png

http://example.com/4.png

http://example.com/9.png

http://example.com/1.png
```

Please correct my code

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:site_loader EXTRACT=HTM

SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {var res=(s.split(i.\".png\").length - 1); MacroError(i); if (res=2) break; }")

TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:/surf/{{res}}.png
```

What else??

How to find 2 same picture and Save or click it ?

Answer (score 1):

For your case I suggest this way:

```
SET listNum EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".match(/\d(?=\.png)/g).toString();")
SET doubleNum EVAL("var d; var a = \"{{listNum}}\".split(\",\"); for (i in a) {if (a.indexOf(a[i]) != i) {d = a[i]; break;}} d;")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:/surf/{{doubleNum}}.png
```